# DocuSign API: Redirection Issues with Envelope Authentication View URLs

Tags: authentication, docusignapi, envelope

We have a DocuSign integration that allows our customers to sign their documents in DocuSign. Here are the steps we follow:

1. We create a new document envelope by hitting the [Envelopes: create](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/v2/reference/envelopes/envelopeviews/createconsole) endpoint.
2. Using the Envelope ID from previous step, we hit the [EnvelopeViews: createConsole](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/v2/reference/envelopes/envelopeviews/createconsole) endpoint to get a redirection URL. We get a URL that looks like this:

   https://demo.docusign.net/Member/StartInSession.aspx?StartConsole=1&t=[GUID]&DocuEnvelope=[ENVELOPE_ID]
3. We redirect our user to the redirection URL from previous step.

**Expected behaviour:** the redirection URL should take our user to the Envelope draft page, i.e. `/prepare/<ENVELOPE_ID>`
**Observed behaviour:** user ends up on DocuSign homepage.

---

We were able to observe the problem when user is not signed into DocuSign, and tries to navigate to the redirection URL:

- When logged in to DocuSign (valid browser session), the redirection URL successfully ends up at the prepare Envelope URL.
- When signed out, the redirection URL takes the user to a sign in page, and after signing in, redirects to the homepage.

ps. We have been using the same work flow with no problems in that past. This issue was brought to our attention a few days ago. (Feb 15 2020)

pps. All users are affected by this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DocuSign has had a few reports of this behavior. The issue is being tracked under ticket number EC-2126 - I'd recommend reaching out to your account team to have your info added to that ticket. If you have a web account, you can email go-live@docusign.com with that issue number and your account ID to have it added.

For the time being, the recommendation is to instead use the CreateSenderView call: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createSender

Comment: Thank you for the quick response Drew! will give this a try and get back to you.

Comment: Drew, this endpoint generates a redirect URL that ends up at `/prepare/ENVELOPD_ID/add_notes`, which is lot better that landing on the homepage. Do you know if there's a way to land on `/prepare/ENVELOPE_ID`?

Comment: The documentation states you can `change the query parameter from send=1 to send=0 to start with the recipients/documents view.` - is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes that's the one, don't know how I missed that :facepalm: Thanks again Drew!

Answer (score 0):

Your step 2 is not right...

### Do you want an embedded **sending** view for the envelope before it is sent to recipients?

Use [EnvelopeViews::createSender](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createSender)

Also, what to you want to happen during the sending view? What is your use case? (Please update/edit your question with the added info.)

### Or an embedded **signing** view? -- The signing ceremony?

Use [EnvelopeViews::createRecipient](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient)